# Is there a proper way to use slow Pokemon in the party?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-fifth-generation

I'm playing Pokemon White 2, and I really love using fast Pokemon in battle. But this time, I think I wanna try to use slow Pokemon in my party. I'm leaning towards using Rock and Steel type Pokemon: Steel and Rock type are the best for great defense, but they have really bad speed in battle.

Here's my current team list.

- Golem
- Aerodactyl (it's fast actually)
- tyranitar
- Magcargo
- Kabutops
- Bastiodon

I just want to know if there is a way use slow Pokemon properly, like their learnset, ability, and move combination for double/triple battle. Is it good to have five Pokemon that really slow at speed?

I'm asking this because I'm curious for the fact that there's many Gym leaders that specialist at Rock and Steel type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In non-competitive scenarios such as playing through the story (which is what you mention that you're playing), it shouldn't really matter too much. You can simply outlevel other trainers and Gym leaders and overwhelm them with pure force.

As for movesets, use your Pokemon's secondary typings to your advantage. For example:

- Use Magcargo's & Aerodactyl's Fire and Flying moves vs Grass & Bug Pokemon,
- Use Tyranitar's Dark moves vs Psychic
- Kabuto's Water vs Fire, Rock and Ground

and so on. Even having Non-[S.T.A.B.](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Same-type_attack_bonus) coverage moves on your Pokemon is worth it. Kabutops can learn Ice Beam, which will be helpful when taking on Dragon types for example.

---

If you want to build a team that actually takes **advantage** of slow Pokemon's speed, you might also want to consider a Team that revolves around [Trick Room](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Trick_Room_(move)):

> Trick Room reverses the move order within each priority bracket so that Pokémon with a lower Speed stat attack first, whilst those with a higher Speed stat will attack last.

If you're looking for Pokemon that can set it up, [Bronzong](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bronzong_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) would be a good example of a Trick Room Pokemon that fits your criteria. It's a slow Steel/Psychic type.

Comment: The only thing that I would add to this is that the current type composition of his team means that his entire team is criplingly weak to Water and Fighting which may present some issues with the Wave Badge and the Fighting member of the Elite Four (although fighting might not be too much of an issue since Aerodactyl should be able to handily out speed everything and deliver 2x STAB-boosted flying damage). Similar weaknesses to ground (though aerodactyl is normally immune). Grass and Steel are also a bit problematic with half the team being weak to those types, and the other half neutral.

Comment: @TrentHawkins Unfortunately dems the breaks when running a mono-type or themed team. As I said the only real way to overcome these problems is to outlevel and have coverage moves, or otherwise have a plan to deal with certain threats on Gym leader/E4 teams (regular trainers won't matter too much). As an example, utilising Golem's Sturdy (assuming it has Sturdy) to survive OHKOs and hit back with a high-powered move is a viable strategy to take care of large threats on the opposing team. Stocking up on Revives and Full Restores is probably a must as well.

Comment: If you want a rock type that helps your weakness to water moves, consider Cradily. It has Storm drain to completely nullify water attacks.

Comment: I would suggest the use of Gyro Ball on either Bronzong or Metagross, both because you would get the STAB and because it's power goes up the lower your Pokemon's speed stat is. So if you combo Gyro Ball with a move like Hammer Arm, then you can drop your speed even lower comparatively and boost Gyro Ball's damage output, and on top of that you can still utilize Trick Room because it doesn't affect the stats themselves so you would still have lower speed than the opposing Pokemon but move before they do.